# Display html of previous element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner.
I want to display the HTML of previous element when the button is clicked.

I am able to display HTML content of button using outerHTML property. But when i use prev() function with the current object, it is showing error.

```
function show(currentObject) {
            alert($(currentObject)[0].outerHTML);
        }
```

above code gives the html content of the current button.
(Click) is shows as alert.

but

```
function show(currentObject) {
            var prevObject = $(currentObject).prev();
            alert($(prevObject)[0].outerHTML);
        }
```

above code is giving me error!!
error: TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined

Below is the html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"><a class="navbar-link" href="/somelink">linktext</a></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><p>click below button</p></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><button onclick="show(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Click</button></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do it right?

Comment: what error you getting, and also show html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pure Javascript use **`previousElementSibling`**

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', currentObject);

function currentObject() {
  alert(this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.outerHTML);
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"><a class="navbar-link" href="/somelink">linktext</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>click below button</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="foo">Click</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.prev().html()` to getting previous element html, check updated snippet below..

```js
alert($('.currentItem').prev().html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">Previous Element</div>
<div class="item1 currentItem">Current Element</div>
```

Comment: No, OP needs outerHTML. So: $('.currentItem').prev()[0].outerHTML

Comment: OP can use `$('.currentItem').prev()get(0).outerHTML` for this

Comment: Yes, right, however, he already got it, but i guess the problem is related to his HTML, or implementation.... :)

Comment: hi I have updated the query with html and correct code snippets.